# PHP sort in alphabatical order

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, templates

So I have on my WordPress site a user page via a template.
the users are loaded via a custom post type called members.

now I have this part to display the users on a template page.
but I need it to be in alphabetical order

the code I have is as follows

**TEMPLATE:**

```
$member_type = (isset($member_type) ? $member_type : 'seb');
$post_type = $member_type == 'seb' ? array('companies', 'members') : 'companies';
// prepare arguments
$args = array(
    'post_type'                 => 'members',
    'orderby'                   => 'name',
    'order'                     => 'ASC',
    'post_status'               => 'publish',
);

// create a query based on arguments
$query = new WP_Query($args);

while ($query->have_posts()):
    $query->the_post();
```

plus I have:

```
<section>
    <p>
        <?php echo (get_field('title') ? get_field('title') . ' ' : '') ?>
        <?php the_field('contactperson') ?>
    </p>
</section>
```

with `'contactperson'` being the member being called up and displayed

so how do I put the output of contact person in alphabetical order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Advanced Custom Fields, but any custom field manager plugin applies. Here is an explanation from the ACF website: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/orde-posts-by-custom-fields/

Bottomline: you need to order by the meta value of your meta key, "contactperson".

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'members',
    'meta_key'          => 'contactperson',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
);
```